# LyX say that no classes are available

Tags: lyx, miktex, installing, document-classes

I'm using LyX for some Maths coursework, I've installed LyX with MiKTeX twice now (re-installed after first encountering this problem) but I'm still getting the same problems.

Basically none of the classes it uses are available. When I load it up it first pops up saying:

> The selected document class Article (Standard Class) requires external files that are not available.

[image]

I am sure it's at least tried to install these files as I saw it come up in the installer's output.. Is this a common problem that anyone knows how to solve?

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: The problem is that LyX does not appear to find the MiKTeX installation. I've seen several issues like this which are specific to Windows. See for example http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/9303 and http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/9256

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to seemingly fix this myself.

I just ran:

```
Tools -> Reconfigure
```